# user group and permission using Spring-Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi i am working on that data model.In which i have tracking of permissions at group level and user level.
i want to implement that solution in spring security.

i) User have number of groups and each group have set of permissions.
ii) permissions are also implemented at user level also to restrict user from some permissions.

my tables are
Users:- userid(pk),username

group:- groupid(pk),groupname

usergroup:- groupid(pk,fk),userid(pk,fk).

permissions:- permissionid,per_name.

group permission:-

user permissions.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security supports group and individual user roles/authorities out of the box. The default schema is described in [an appendix in the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#appendix-schema).

If you want to use your own schema, you can either inject custom SQL into [JdbcDaoImpl](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java) which returns the same data it expects, or, if your schema is too different, you can implement your own `UserDetailsService` to load the data yourself.